# ODBC connects, but MsAccess 2016 won't

Tags: odbc, ms-access-2016

Hello been struggling with this one:

Up until a few months ago I had an MSAccess 2010 database, it's matching SQL ODBC and life was good.

Then came MSAccess 2016 with a new laptop and now whenever I try to use the old database (and I've created fresh ones in the new version just to test), MsAccess will return an error:

a) SQL Server Error 53: About Failed Connection

b) SQL Server Error 17: Server does not exist or access is denied.
(I use linked tables and with queries I import the data needed)

What really complicates things to diagnose is that:

- When you test the ODBC connectivity by itself, the test come back "successful".
- I tried pairing the ODBC with Excel, and it did get through, I could see the table list to link.. so again, the ODBC works.
- If I log into the work's VPN (even while being connected to the work internal network)... MsAccess 2016 queries magically work as intended.

So, there is something I'm missing with Access itself and some network setting somewhere, but my own IT department is stumped.

Any ideas are welcome on what may be happening. Thanks!

Comment: Did you relink the tables in Access? And /or talk to your network admin what the VPN connection does in relation to your Access application.